# How to end a do while loop with string user input for an array

Tags: java

I am trying to get my do-while loop to end, and I can't figure out how. The print statement has stopped, but the code after the do-while loop isn't running.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dogs;

    System.out.println("How many dogs?");
    dogs = input.nextInt();


    String[] dognames = new String[dogs];
    Double[] dogweights = new Double[dogs];

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < dogs; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
            dognames[i] = input.next();
            dogweights[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    } while ((!"quit".equals(dognames)));


    double length = dogweights.length;


    double sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < dogweights.length; i++) {
        sum += dogweights[i];
    }

    double dogweightsaverage = sum / length;

    System.out.print("test");
}
```

The loop isn't finishing, the print statement stopped but the code after the loop isn't printing

Comment: `dognames` is an array. `"quit".equals(dognames)` can never be true. And you negate that. So it'll loop forever.  Perhaps you wanted `!"quit".equals(dognames[i])` **note** that then `length` is not `dogweights.length`. It's `i` where `i` has already gone out of scope.

Comment: The `.equals` method overridden `.equals (Object o)` in `class Object`. That means the argument passed to `.equals` can be *any* reference type. And an array qualifies as a reference type. This returns `false` because the overridden method of `String` asks if the argument passed is an `instanceof String`. An array of `String` is not a `String`, so the `instanceof` test fails.

Comment: Even after you fix the problem with comparing a single `String` to an array, you have another problem: Your `for` loop is in a `do ... while` loop. So, you iterate the `for` loop `dogs` number of times. Then, if the last dog name isn't `quit`, the `do ... while` starts  next iteration, and the `for` loop begins over again. Each iteration of the `for` loop overwrites a `dogNames [i]` and a `dogWeights[i]` from the previous iteration. Use the `for` loop when you know in advance the number of dogs that will have data entered. Use the `while` loop when you don't know in advance the number of dogs

Comment: Off-topic: You don't need a 2nd `for` loop to calculate average. You can calculate `sum` in the same loop where the dogs' weights are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Your exit condition needs adjusting to check *the last* added name, which requires the condition to be with the *scope* of that info - ie *outside* the loop.

Try this:

```
String dogname = null;
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < dogs; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
        dogname = dognames[i] = input.next();
        dogweights[i]=input.nextDouble();
    }
} while(!"quit".equals(dogname));
```

Note that you'll then have to ignore the "quit" name in your array. Consider not using a `do while` and just `break` out on "quit" *before* adding it to the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogs; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
    String dogname = input.next();
    if ("quit".equals(dogname)) {
        break;
    }
    dognames[i] = dogname;
    dogweights[i]=input.nextDouble();
}
```

Which also narrows the scope of `dogname`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a while loop, like so:

```
int i = 0;

System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
String dogname = input.next();
while (i < dogs && !dogname.equals("quit")) {
    dognames[i] = dogname;
    dogweights[i]=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
    dogname = input.next();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is better to encapsulate all dog's data within one class:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static final class Dog {
    private final String name;
    private final double weight;
}
```

Then you should use `for...loop` to iterate over an array and fill it with data from the console.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useLocale(Locale.US);  // read double correctly

    System.out.print("How many dogs: ");
    Dog[] dogs = readDogs(scan.nextInt(), scan);

    System.out.println();

    double avgWeight = getAverageWeight(dogs);
    System.out.format(Locale.US, "Average weight: %.2f\n", avgWeight);
}

private static Dog[] readDogs(int total, Scanner scan) {
    Dog[] dogs = new Dog[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
        System.out.format("Dog %d name: ", i + 1);
        scan.nextLine();    // feature of Scanner
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.format("Dog %d weight: ", i + 1);
        double weight = scan.nextDouble();

        dogs[i] = new Dog(name, weight);
    }

    return dogs;
}

private static double getAverageWeight(Dog... dogs) {
    return Arrays.stream(dogs)
                 .mapToDouble(Dog::getWeight)
                 .average().orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```